# How to find maximum value across several lists stored in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Another question about lists. Say I have a dataframe containing several lists. Assume they're the results of an American election. They include the vote shares for Democrats, Republicans, and Third Party candidates across three simulations for three states:

```
list1 <- list(c(40, 44, 52))
list2 <- list(c(22, 36, 18))
list3 <- list(c(45, 37, 42))

list4 <- list(c(60, 56, 48))
list5 <- list(c(34, 52, 26))
list6 <- list(c(55, 63, 58))

list7 <- list(c(0, 0, 0))
list8 <- list(c(44, 12, 56))
list9 <- list(c(0, 0, 0))

dat <- data.frame(State = c("Iowa", "Wisconsin", "Ohio"))
dat$DemocratVoteShare <- c(list1, list2, list3)
dat$RepublicanVoteShare <- c(list4, list5, list6)
dat$ThirdPartyVoteShare <- c(list7, list8, list9)
```

Note that Wisconsin is the only state with a Third Party candidate.

I'm trying to evaluate when a party had the *maximum* vote share in a state for a given simulation. The results would look like this:

```
dat$Winner <- c(list(c("Republican", "Republican", "Democrat")),
                list(c("Third Party", "Republican", "Third Party")),
                list(c("Republican", "Republican", "Republican")))
```

How can I achieve this using R, and ideally functionality from the `tidyverse`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(
    Winner = Map(function(x, y, z) {
      c("Democrat", "Republican", "Third Party")[max.col(cbind(x, y ,z) == pmax(x, y ,z))]
    }, DemocratVoteShare, RepublicanVoteShare, ThirdPartyVoteShare)
  )
```

Output

```
      State DemocratVoteShare RepublicanVoteShare ThirdPartyVoteShare                               Winner
1      Iowa        40, 44, 52          60, 56, 48             0, 0, 0     Republican, Republican, Democrat
2 Wisconsin        22, 36, 18          34, 52, 26          44, 12, 56 Third Party, Republican, Third Party
3      Ohio        45, 37, 42          55, 63, 58             0, 0, 0   Republican, Republican, Republican
```

**Update**

As pointed out by @akrun, you can use `max.col` directly, and it allows you to select a `ties.method`.

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(
    Winner = Map(function(x, y, z) {
      c("Democrat", "Republican", "Third Party")[max.col(cbind(x, y ,z), "first")]
    }, DemocratVoteShare, RepublicanVoteShare, ThirdPartyVoteShare)
  )
```

The code above gives higher priority to the option "Democrat". If you want to use "Republican" instead, then swap their positions like this

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(
    Winner = Map(function(x, y, z) {
      c("Republican", "Democrat", "Third Party")[max.col(cbind(x, y ,z), "first")]
    }, RepublicanVoteShare, DemocratVoteShare, ThirdPartyVoteShare)
  )
```

Comment: Very handy. Thanks, @ekoam!

Comment: Do you know how this logic goes about breaking ties? Is it at random? Is there a way to force the tie to break towards, say, Democrats?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pmap`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
dat %>%
   mutate(Winner = pmap(select(cur_data(), -State),
      ~ c("Democrat", "Republican", "Third Party")[max.col(cbind(..1, ..2, ..3))]))
#      State DemocratVoteShare RepublicanVoteShare ThirdPartyVoteShare                               Winner
#1      Iowa        40, 44, 52          60, 56, 48             0, 0, 0     Republican, Republican, Democrat
#2 Wisconsin        22, 36, 18          34, 52, 26          44, 12, 56 Third Party, Republican, Third Party
#3      Ohio        45, 37, 42          55, 63, 58             0, 0, 0   Republican, Republican, Republican
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you `unnest` the data.

```
library(dplyr)

val <- sub('VoteShare', '', names(dat[-1]))

dat %>%
  tidyr::unnest(-State) %>%
  mutate(Winner = val[max.col(.[-1], ties.method = 'first')])

#  State     DemocratVoteShare RepublicanVoteShare ThirdPartyVoteShare Winner    
#  <chr>                 <dbl>               <dbl>               <dbl> <chr>     
#1 Iowa                     40                  60                   0 Republican
#2 Iowa                     44                  56                   0 Republican
#3 Iowa                     52                  48                   0 Democrat  
#4 Wisconsin                22                  34                  44 ThirdParty
#5 Wisconsin                36                  52                  12 Republican
#6 Wisconsin                18                  26                  56 ThirdParty
#7 Ohio                     45                  55                   0 Republican
#8 Ohio                     37                  63                   0 Republican
#9 Ohio                     42                  58                   0 Republican
```